# User agents for mobile site, domain changing

Tags: php, mobile-phones, mobile-website

I have a mobile site and I'd like to redirect users to the domain.mobi or mobile.subdomain (we have both setup)

1. How do I determine  a mobile browser

   Is it bad practice to have the mobile site on a different domain or subdomain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. How do I determine a mobile browser

Here's some javascript that will do the job:  http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

> 2. Is it bad practice to have the mobile site on a different domain or
>      subdomain?

It's good practice, and a popular convention is to use http://m.yoursite.com for mobile if your main url is http://yoursite.com

Noah

Comment: It´s difficult use js to determinate mobile browsers, because most them don´t support js. I recomend you use WURFL.
http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

It isn't bad practice.  I appreciate when sites do this -- and I like it if they include a link for me to get to the real site if I want.

I found this list in google -- there are other hits if you search for them

http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html

Comment: It isnt bad practice if the site allows to view the normal version too explicitly requested.  One real-world example if this is that some websites see nokia in user-agent and they forward you to their "mobile" site but totally ignore the fact that nokia N8XX series has full blown browser.  Or in similar matter, some wap sites doesnt allow their "content to be seen" because useragent is not know to them.

Comment: My iPhone browser is awesome, but on sites that give me a mobile version, it's even better.  GMail is a simple example.  The screen is smaller and it's harder to click things -- I appreciate a custom UI.  But, since the UI is sometimes limited, it's nice to get the real site if I want it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of solutions for determining mobile browsers. Most use the UserAgent making the request but some solutions use other factors as well.

Try looking at:

[WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/)

[MDBF](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/)

[DeviceAtlas](http://deviceatlas.com/)

[DetectRight](http://www.detectright.com/)

[Volantis](http://www.volantis.com/)

[MobileAware](http://www.mobileaware.com/)

[Movila](http://www.moviladetection.com/)

[UAProf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UAProf)