# Any PHP User Agent detection scripts for mobile phones only?

Tags: php, android, ios, user-agent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [User agents for mobile site, domain changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034222/user-agents-for-mobile-site-domain-changing)

I have an optimized version of my website for mobile phones that I'd like to suggest to my visitors they visit if using a mobile phone.  I know it's a bad idea to rely on screen resolution because many tablets today are simialr to desktops in terms of resolution.

Is there a suggested PHP user agent detection script for mobile phones only?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

Comment: @Tucia Not sure how I missed that one, been searching on google but couldn't find anything good. Thanks!